# Display a div above a grid grow

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a display grid with multiple rows and multiple columns, I am trying to make a div display when I hover over one of the grid boxes, but right now it is being cut off by a grid row. I want it to lay over the design.

I have tried position: absolute and z-index, but that does not seem to work. What other ideas can I try?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. [https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocodeforreview/](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocodeforreview/)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to using absolute and z-index you should probably position the div you want to display over the others in the largest parent div. If you are able to provide your html and css I can be more precise